# Getting error in query population in mongoose v6

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I want to populate the category field in product schema.

The code for my product schema is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const {ObjectId} = mongoose.Schema 
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

name :{
type:String,
required : true,
trim : true,
maxlength : 32,
},

description : {
  type:String,
  required : true,
  trim : true,
  maxlength : 2000,
},
price : {
  type : Number,
  required : true,
  maxlength  :32
},
category : {
  type : ObjectId,
  ref : "Category", 
  required : true
},
stock : {
type : Number,
},
sold : {
type  :Number,
default  : 0
},
photo : {
  data : Buffer, 
   contentType : String 
 }

 },{timestamps:true})


 module.exports = mongoose.model("Product",productSchema);
```

And The code which i am using to populate the category field is

```
exports.getAllProducts = (req,res)=>{

let no_of_products = req.query.limit? parseInt(req.query.limit):8;
let sortBy = req.query.sortBy?req.query.sortBy : "price"



Product.find()
.populate("catgeory")
.select("-photo")
.sort({sortBy:1})
.limit(no_of_products)
.exec((err,products)=>{
 if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(400).json({
       error : "some error occured"
    })
  }

})
}
```

But this code is giving me error which say

cannot populate path `Catgeory` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to false to override.

I have read documentation but i am unable to alter my code . Kindly help me with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

check the Product databases table that you have category keys and you  should know that the object Id is correct and it comes from the category table if not you should drop the database or drop the product collection and create the new one

Comment: There is category key and also the objectId is correct but still getting these errors

Comment: try to drop the product collection and create the new one